# How to add tab to webUI in openwrt

Tags: openwrt

I'm wondering if it is possible to add (install) LUCI plugin (i mean add new element or tab to the current webUI) without the need to compile the entire image, just like creating and installing package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i found how to add tab to the current WebUI, it was kinda tricky (or confusing) for someone noob like me in LUCI and openwrt in general, all i had to do is just to create the LUCI CBI controller and the models files (.lua) and upload them to the correct path to openwrt, and because i'm already creating my package so i just had to add them to the install file and in the installation just copy them to the right folder (/usr/lib/lua/luci) via makefile and everything went good.

those links helped me a lot.

> http://www.electronicsfaq.com/2018/01/adding-new-elements-to-openwrts-luci-on.html
>   https://oldwiki.archive.openwrt.org/doc/devel/luci